# Pinpointing a memory leak in a small Node.js project: Where should I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been working on a small Node.js project of some ~1000 LOC, and I've encountered a severe memory leak. I've already done the usual research with no luck, so I'd love to get some help locating it, but I'm not sure that Stack Overflow or Code Review are appropriate venues for such a potentially specific question.

Does my question belong anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, and if not, is there somewhere else I can ask it?

Comment: Nowhere on SE I can think of... maybe ask in chat with a gist and see if someone is interested

Comment: I don't think that a canonical "how to debug a node.js memory leak" Q+A would be offtopic so you could try to motivate people for that on the chat or here on meta.

Comment: You'll most likely solve it yourself while creating an MCVE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*In practice*, debugging Node.js is hard, and we need more good questions. Please ask it. [You will still want to demonstrate some of your research effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/how-does-proof-of-effort-make-a-question-better) - what you Googled, what advice you got, and why it didn't work - for the post to be well-received.

But really, Node.js is hard, please do.

Sorry for the second answer, but I thought the domain expertise regarding my personal knowledge of the Node.js Q&A is relevant. I think a "general" question with a decent stab at research effort will be well-received and add value.

Comment: I'll go ahead and do that, then. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: But he would need to make the question ontopic here, i.e. produce a minimal example showing the problem (question about debugging help etcetera...).

Answer (score 4):

The other answers here cover why the question would be good for Stack Overflow and how to ask it well, but I would like to add a note about your thought of posting it on Code Review:

Your question would very likely be closed on Code Review. Debugging questions are specifically off-topic there, and that site requires working code. The purpose of Code Review is to get feedback on the quality of working code you have written, to improve things like use of idioms, optimizations, and maintainability, not functionality.

Comment: What about if it was just asked about doing a code review on code that works, but otherwise happens to have a memory leak? Code review indeed isn't for picking on "fix this problem for me" but rather "here is some code, review all aspects of it."  As a side effect, someone may spot the memory leak, but the goal would be to review the code of working code.

Comment: If you mention there is a leak, I think it will still have a good chance of getting closed. They heavily emphasize the importance of having working code, because if there are still issues to fix, then the code is surely going to be changed, so why not just wait to get the review? I suppose that pretending you don't know the memory leak is there may keep it from being closed, but that's a pretty roundabout way of solving your issue. I think fixing the leak with SO's help, *then* going to CR to get a review would be the way to go.

Comment: CodeReview does a [Fagan inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagan_inspection) of working code. A memory leak is just as working code [as a performance issue](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73653/first-four-project-euler-in-scala#comment133883_73653) (which is on topic on code review). If there are issues with the working code that an inspection would identify because of some oversight, that is part of the review. Recall though that this is a *review* - not debugging. Answers that miss a memory leak are just as correct as those that identify it.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that questions about memory leaks and questions about performance are in the same category. Lower "performance" can sometimes be by design, such as sacrificing speed for code readability, and thus isn't a bug. Discussions about performance have a lot of gray areas, and are good teaching points in a code review. However, memory leaks are *never* okay, and are *never* intentional, so I would consider their presence a bug. Because of that distinction, if I came across a question on CR where the OP acknowledged the memory leak, I would consider the code not working.

Comment: This would be something interesting to take meta.codereview.  I would direct you to a [past discussion there](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/are-code-snippets-with-known-memory-leaks-broken#comment6030_2340) or [this one](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3842/22048).  Its complicated (note - both have opinions given by current moderators who put it at worst in a gray area).

Answer (score 2):

Well... in chat!

You're welcome to drop by in [the JavaScript chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) to get general advice on debugging node or tracking down leaks. Dumping your whole project in SO will likely not help any future visitors as it is and not get attention - in chat people might take a look and help you diagnose your problem - this sort of problem solving requires a lot of back-and-forth.

There is a lot of opinionated advice chat can give you that helps debugging the main site simply can't because it's timely or opinionated.

Of course it's also entirely possible chat will just ignore you - but it's definitely worth a try.

When you figure out what went wrong take any reusable information possible out of it and convert it into canonical Q&As that would have helped you a-priori - these tend to be very rewarding and well received in the community.

Comment: -1, I think it's a lot more important to write a good question for SO (and the OP does have a *far* better question in there than many acceptable questions).

Comment: @djechlin out of all memory bugs I debugged maybe one or two would be suitable for chat. "How to debug memory" is too broad and you can't ask anything specific since you don't get an exception or know where the bug is.